# Error: Function Templates, cannot convert , from 'int' to 'double'

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a function template

```
template <class T>
T max(T& t1, T& t2)
{
    return t1 < t2 ? t2 : t1;
}
```

and i call it as
 `max<double>(33, 44.2)`, so i am expecting it will convert int to double and give me the result in double, instead i am getting an error:

**cannot convert , from 'int' to 'double'**

Comment: Change the template parameters to `const T &`. Non-`const` references cannot be bound to temporaries.

Comment: That's not the error you're getting.  You're trying to pass off a constant as an lvalue.  Use `T const& tn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would work without references (or with const references):

```
template <class T>
T max(T t1, T t2)
{
    return t1 < t2 ? t2 : t1;
}
```

and then

```
max<double>(33, 44.2)
```

Comment: The [proof](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e498db6586762fd). You ninja'd my answer :P